# how to add a menuitem inheritance in an internal module odoo for example CRM?

Tags: python, xml, inheritance, menuitem, odoo-12

How to add a menuitem inheritance in an internal module odoo for example CRM?

I try this but I think it does not mean anything

```xml
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="crm_geo_list">
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_menu_root"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <menuitem parent="crm.crm_menu_root" position="inside" id="main_geoagenc" name="Agenc Geo"/>
    </field>
</record>
```

Comment: sorry @barbsan, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can't inherited the menuitem you want to change in default menuitem just overwrite it like this..

```
<menuitem id="crm.crm_config_settings_menu"
        name="Settings"
        parent="crm.crm_menu_config"
        action="crm.crm_config_settings_action"
        groups="base.group_system"
        sequence="0"/>
```

and you can add the menu in child of that so.. you can add new menu in your module and add in parent of the default so it will add on that parent.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but do you mean that I have to manually edit the view code of Odoo's internal CRM?

Comment: what I want to do exactly is to create a module that will integrate a view <menuitem> in the CRM internal module so as not to modify in the basic CRM view